# Download Android Vitals (Crashes and ANRs) Details from Google Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I need to download Crash and ANR details from Google Play console and create internal Jiras for developers to address these vitals. Using GSUTIL - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export, we can download crash and ANR stats by Android version, device and app version. However, I am looking for options to download Crash and ANR details including Stack Trace.

Comment: can you tell us please did you find a solution?